# I just upgraded to 22.04 LTS and all my symlinks are broken / drives mount with new names

Tags: upgrade, mount, 22.04, symbolic-link

I just tried to upgrade to 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) (from previous LTS)

There were some issues, it said it couldn't do the whole thing, but it could download some packages. Eventually I seem to have forced it to upgrade lots of packages to JJ ones.

Then I logged out and in again.

And now all my symlinks claim to be broken. Or rather, on further investigation, the old mount points of my other drives now belong to root and are empty, and when I mount them through nautilus, they get new names. So all the symlinks that referred to the old names are broken.

```
 ls -la /media/phil/
total 56
drwxr-x---+ 12 root root 4096 mai 23 11:15 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 out 27  2020 ..
drwx------   2 root root 4096 mai 22 14:56 151848002EC71722
drwxrwxrwx   1 phil phil 8192 mai 22 13:40 151848002EC717221
drwx------   2 root root 4096 mai 22 14:57 6692A2ED312E3FFA
drwxrwxrwx   1 phil phil 4096 mai 20 19:11 6692A2ED312E3FFA1
drwx------   2 root root 4096 mai 22 14:57 96963E84963E6541
drwxrwxrwx   1 phil phil 8192 mai 20 19:09 96963E84963E65411
```

Previously the drives were called things like 6692A2ED312E3FFA. Now that name seems to have been grabbed by root. So when I try to navigate to the drive in nautilus (which works), it mounts with the name 6692A2ED312E3FFA1

But this breaks all my symlinks which referred to 6692A2ED312E3FFA

What can I do about this? Is it safe to try to remove the old names of the mount points in the hope that it will remount the drives them with the original names if I log out?

Any other solutions?

Comment: "*it said it couldn't do the whole thing, but it could download some packages.*" That's a huge red flag. Usually, we call that a *failed attempt* to release-upgrade. Serious problems (like you encountered) are expected after such. Some can be repaired; some require a reinstall.

Comment: best practice is to mount drives in fstab with the UUID which will preserve the mount points and not leave things to chance.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I took the plunge. Logged out and logged in again. None of the drives were mounted automatically. So sudo su-ed to root and deleted all the names in /mount/phil.

Then when I went to mount them through nautilus they got mounted again with their original names so the symlinks are ok.

Hope this helps anyone else in this situation.